# Print file name within generator of during Pandas Concat pd.concat

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm loading thousands of files that is supposed to have the same structure through pd.concat using a generator from the list of files in a given directory.

Is there anyway I can print f within this generator for debugging purpose? I'd like to know which file causes the failure. Thank you all in advance!

```
files   = glob.glob(input_dir + "/*.csv")
df      = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `try..except` to properly handle loading the file and printing the potential error. Here's an example:

```
files   = glob.glob(input_dir + "/*.csv")

def load_file(f):
   """Loads a csv file into a dataframe"""
   try:
       # Load the file if there is no problem
       return pd.read_csv(f)
   except Exception as e:
       # If there is a problem
       # print an error message with the name of the file
       print("Loading file {} failed with error: {}"
             .format(f, e.message))
       # return an empty dataframe so the pd.concat won't fail.
       return pd.DataFrame()

df = pd.concat((load_file(f) for f in all_files))
```